# IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views

I was referring to this page of [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/) to write views. Can someone explain what I did wrong ? And what could be the solution

```
    self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
  File "/vagrant/projects/kodeworms/course/views.py", line 23, in get_queryset
    self.Course = get_object_or_404(Course, name=self.args[0])
  IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

My views.py file

```
# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from .models import Course, Content


class PublishedCourseMixin(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(PublishedCourseMixin, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(published_course=True)


class CourseListView(PublishedCourseMixin, ListView):
    model = Course
    template_name = 'course/course_list.html'

class CourseContentListView(ListView):
    model = Content
    template_name = 'course/content_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.Course = get_object_or_404(Course, name=self.args[0])
        return Content.objects.filter(course=self.course, published=True)
```

My urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^$", views.CourseListView.as_view(), name="list" ),
    url(r"^(?P<slug_topic_name>[\w-]+)/$", views.CourseContentListView.as_view(), name="list"),
)
```

Comment: Could you post your entire def get_queryset(self), please? Also as I suspect you've followed the tutorial, how are you accessing this view?

Comment: I guess `self.args` is empty.

Comment: How are you accessing it? Your `args` is empty thats why youre getting that error.

Comment: @limelights I'm beginner in both python n django. What would you recommend me to do/read ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `self.args[0]` which is for positional arguments, but you are passing in a keyword argument to your view.

As you have no positional arguments `self.args` is a zero-length tuple which is why you get that exception.

You should be using `self.kwargs['slug_topic_name']` since you have a keyword argument in your url.

Comment: 'FieldError at /course/html5/

Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: author, content, course_name, id, pub_date, published_course, slug' This is the error I'm getting now

Comment: That means your `Course` object has no field `name`. You should use `self.course = get_object_or_404(Course, course_name=self.kwargs.get('slug_topic_name')`. Also, I would always use `self.kwargs.get('<fieldname>')` instead of `self.kwargs['<fieldname.']` to prevent an `IndexError` when you actually want to throw a `Http404`.

Comment: As the URL is mapped to the view, there is no way the view would be called without a keyword argument (unless, the OP decided to manually call it somewhere else in the code, or map it to another URL by mistake). In either case, dictionaries do not raise `IndexError`, they raise `KeyError`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Thanks Bro it helped me clear basic concepts and with other problems too.. Cheers to you !! :)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Could you tell me what is the use ```*args``` here?

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to this url

```
url(r"^$", views.CourseListView.as_view(), name="list" ),
```

there is no self.args, you should check it

I suppose, it will work if you will go to this url

```
url(r"^(?P<slug_topic_name>[\w-]+)/$", views.CourseContentListView.as_view(), name="list"),
```

Comment: I'm trying for that url only