# Dynamic filtering of objects in one to many relationship model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I want to access the list of contents which belongs to a particular courses. How should I write my views and urls to access it. I have written views and urls for course list but some how can't get to contents inside each course

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
import datetime 
from django.utils import timezone
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify



class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def live(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(published=True)



class Course(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="courses")
    published_course = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    objects = PostManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-pub_date", "course_name"]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.course_name

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date < now

    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently ?'   

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.course_name)
        super(Course, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @models.permalink   
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ("course:detail", (), {"slug": self.slug})


class Content(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    topic_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug_topic_name = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
    desc = models.TextField()
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    objects = PostManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.topic_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug_topic_name:
            self.slug_topic_name = slugify(self.topic_name)
        super(Content, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @models.permalink   
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ("content:detail", (), {"slug_topic_name": self.slug_topic_name})
```

My course/views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from .models import Course, Content


class CourseListView(ListView):
    model = Course

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(CourseListView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(published_course=True)

class CourseContentListView(ListView):

    context_object_name = 'content_list'
    queryset = Content.objects.filter(course__course_name='HTML5')
    template_name = 'content/content_list.html'
```

My course/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^$", views.CourseListView.as_view(), name="list" ),
    url(r"^(?P<course_name>[\w-]+)/$", views.CourseContentListView.as_view(), name="list"),
)
```

project/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin


from . import views

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'kodeworms.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^kodeworms/', include('kodeworms.foo.urls')),
    url(r"^$", views.HomepageView.as_view(), name="home"),
    url(r"^course/", include("course.urls", namespace="course")),
    url(r"^course/content", include("course.urls", namespace="content")),   

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

project\course\templates\course\course_list.html

```
{% extends "_layouts/base.html" %}
{% load url from future %}

{% block page_title %}Course List | {% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
<h2>Course Grid</h2>

<ul>
    {% for course in course_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'content:list' %}">{{ course.course_name }}</a></li>
    {% empty %}
    <li>Sorry, no courses yet. Check back soon! </li>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><a href="{% url 'home' %}">&larr; Home</a></p>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

project\course\templates\content\content_list.html

```
{% extends "_layouts/base.html" %}

{% block page_title %}{{ course.course_name }} | {% endblock %}


{% block page_content %}
<h2>{{ course.course_name }}</h2>
{{ course.content|linebreaks }}

<ul>
    {% for content in object_list %}
    <li>{{ content.topic_name }}</li>
    {% empty %}
    <li>Sorry, no content yet. Check back soon! </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<p><a href="{% url 'course:list' %}">&larr; Course List</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

In above code I have hard-coded the course name for its content. I want to obtain it dynamically for any arbitrary course. Also my pk=1 gives error, pk=8/9/10 has values. can someone please help

Comment: show us the faulty code.

Comment: @karthikr sorry for late update.. slow internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is my First Web project and off-course first Django project after poll app. So this soln. is for those who are noobs/beginners like me to the world of programming/web-dev.

My pk was starting from pk=8, so I couldn't figure out to how access the content list with it. But then with some Django documentation reading and answer from this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906936/indexerror-tuple-index-out-of-range) I was able to figure out the problem and worked my way through it. Anyways here's modified code

views.py -> earlier the course was hard-coded to access the content list and I was also trying to access the contents dynamically with primary key (with which I was unsuccessful). So Now I tried to access it with slug and was successful.

```
class CourseContentListView(ListView):

    template_name = 'course/content_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.course = get_object_or_404(Course, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return Content.objects.filter(course=self.course, published=True)
```

I also read some more about Django templates from official docs and figure out the right way to name and access urls and made changes to course_list.html to access content list

course_list.html

```
<ul>
    {% for course in course_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'course:content_list' course.slug %}">{{ course.course_name }}</a></li>
    {% empty %}
    <li>Sorry, no courses yet. Check back soon! </li>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><a href="{% url 'home' %}">&larr; Home</a></p>

</ul>
```

Changed urls.py to correctly point to the appropriate url

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^$", views.CourseListView.as_view(), name="list" ),
    url(r"^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$", views.CourseContentListView.as_view(), name="content_list"),
)
```

I'm still learning so there can be mistakes in the above code or even better/elegant ways to do it. But then again, this code worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = Course.objects.get(pk=1)
# List of contents for this course
course_contents = a.content_set.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your CourseContentListView to:

```
class CourseContentListView(ListView):

    model = Content
    context_object_name = 'content_list'
    template_name = 'content/content_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(CourseContentListView, self).get_queryset()
        course_name = self.kwargs.get('course_name')
        course = Course.objects.get(course_name=course_name)
        queryset = queryset.filter(course=course)
        return queryset
```

Comment: thanksfor your input but the above code give error 'Course matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'course_name': None}'